# reset $PATH homebrew

Tags: path, homebrew, iterm

I'm very new to coding and I was beginning to set up my development environment according to a Mackenzie Child youtube video. After downloading iTerm and installing homebrew, I was having trouble with updating the Ruby 2.0.0 version to 2.2.2. In the video Mackenzie changes his ~/.bash_profile and restarts iTerm to resolve the problem. I did the same thing except now iTerm doesn't recognize any commands. I can't access bash_profile or run any commands.

I believe the problem occurred when I changed my bash_profile except I can't access/find it anywhere. The command line doesn't let me access it either.I can't find any solutions to my specific problem online so I'm grateful if anyone can help.

[Screenshot of iTerm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hn0m.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If restarting iTerm didn't fix your problem, then:

1. Open iterm.
2. Run `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin` .
3. Run `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` .  Paste what's in that file here.